# Block dotfiles in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I want to allow uploading (all possible) image files through a carrierwave uploader.

Unfortunately it's possible that dotfiles such as `.DS_STORE` might get passed to the uploader. I tried adding an explicit whitelist to only allow image-formats that I know of, but that didn't help.

```
def extension_whitelist
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

Also tried running all the files through a regexp and only allow matches

```
def extension_whitelist
  [/^[^\.].*$/]
end
```

This also did not work.
Adding a blacklist was no help either

```
def extension_blacklist
  %w(.ds_store .DS_STORE ds_store DS_STORE)
end
```

Here's my model

```
class LocalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image_file, ImageUploader
  process_in_background :image_file

  validates_integrity_of :image_file
end
```

Here's the uploader in question

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

I added the backlist/whitelist definitions and tested them all through (had the server restarted in between to ensure no caching issues). Also tested through the console but the model is always `valid` and does not throw an error upon `create!`ing.

```
path = "path_to_file/.DS_STORE"
File.exists?(path) # => true

local_image = LocalImage.new(image_file: File.open(path, 'rb'))
local_image.valid? # => true
local_image.save! # => true

LocalImage.create!(image_file: File.open(path, 'rb'))
# => <LocalImage id: 22325, code: nil, image_id: nil, image_file: ".DS_STORE", created_at: "2018-02-02 11:19:25", updated_at: "2018-02-02 11:19:25", import_filename: ".ds_store">
```

Running

- Rails 4.2.0
- Carrierwave 0.10.0
- carrierwave_backgrounder 0.4.2
- mini_magick 4.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1896#issuecomment-208846564) the method `extension_whitelist` only existed from version 0.11 on, so the version I am using didn't have this change yet.
I could fix the validation by either upgrading `carrierwave` to 0.11 or renaming my `extension_whitelist` to `extension_white_list`. (Same with `blacklist -> black_list`).